# 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' while importing excel in dataset using OpenXML

Tags: c#, excel, dataset, openxml

I'm working on windows application where I import multiple excel file one by one in dataset file which may contain multiple sheets.
I'm using OpenXML for that, currently, its work finely when there is only one excel file but it gives exception while importing multiple excel I got "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." exception.

here is the method i used

```cs
internal DataSet GetDataFromExcelsxFile(string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        KeywordFiles objKeywordFilesController = new KeywordFiles();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, false))
        {

            WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
            IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>();
            foreach (var item in sheets)
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                string relationshipId = item.Id.Value;
                WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);
                Worksheet workSheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
                SheetData sheetData = workSheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
                IEnumerable<Row> rows = sheetData.Descendants<Row>();

                /*Exception getting on this loop start*/
                foreach (Cell cell in rows.ElementAtOrDefault(0))
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(GetCellValue(spreadSheetDocument, cell));
                }

                foreach (Row row in rows) //this will also include your header row...
                {
                    DataRow tempRow = dt.NewRow();

                    for (int i = 0; i < row.Descendants<Cell>().Count(); i++)
                    {
                        tempRow[i] = GetCellValue(spreadSheetDocument, row.Descendants<Cell>().ElementAt(i));
                    }

                    dt.Rows.Add(tempRow);
                }
                dt.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
                ds.Tables.Add(dt);

            }
        }

        return ds

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.LogInfo(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + "\n" + "Exception occured to - " + fullName + " \n: " + ex.Message);
        //DialogResult dr = RadMessageBox.Show("Exception occured to - " + fullName + " \n: " + ex.Message, "Error Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OK, RadMessageIcon.Error);

    }

}

public static string GetCellValue(SpreadsheetDocument document, Cell cell)
{
    SharedStringTablePart stringTablePart = document.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart;
    string value = cell.CellValue.InnerXml;

    if (cell.DataType != null && cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)
    {
        return stringTablePart.SharedStringTable.ChildElements[Int32.Parse(value)].InnerText;
    }
    else
    {
        return value;
    }
}

/* Exception getting on this loop start

     foreach (Cell cell in rows.ElementAtOrDefault(0))
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(GetCellValue(spreadSheetDocument, cell));
                }

i tried rows.ElementAt(0) instead of rows.ElementAtOrDefault(0) but still getting same exception
*/
```

Comment: ..You could tell us where you encounter the exception. I'll not start guessing..

Comment: ok i will edit my query..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NullReferenceException` is thrown because, in the line of code you already marked, `rows.ElementAtOrDefault(0)` returns `null`. This happens if the `SheetData` instance does not contain any `Row` instances.

```cs
IEnumerable<Row> rows = sheetData.Descendants<Row>();

/*Exception getting on this loop start*/
foreach (Cell cell in rows.ElementAtOrDefault(0))
{
    // Loop body removed
}
```

Your code should never throw a `NullReference` exception. In this case, the culprit is the term `rows.ElementAtOrDefault(0)`, which can return `null` and, thus, should not be used in a `foreach` loop.

Further, `Cell cell in rows.ElementAtOrDefault(0)` is not a good practice and can lead to further issues. In this case, a `Row` instance can contain both `Cell` and `ExtensionList` child instances, which can lead to type casting exceptions.

Comment: @T.Giri, could you please mark this as the answer as well?